# Update the view in the MainActivity immediately from the server

Tags: android

I am createing checkbox list from an arrayList that I am getting from the Server, programmatically.The checkBox list is being created but I am facing problem that the value change in the MySQL table every minute. Regarding, I have to update the values of checkboxes list in the MainActivity. Is there any way in Android to update the values (getText) of the checkboxes in the MainActivity immediately like Ajax in JavaScript?

What I am trying to achieve, to rebuild the check box list in the MainActivity when value of the tables's record changes immediately. Which approach can I use to achieve that or the best what I can achieve, to remove the chechbox list element from the xml file and then send a new request to the Server periodically?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Use an AsyncTask that every minute update the value from server. That's all..

Comment: @End.Game: I am already using asynctask to get the arrayList from the Server how can I send the request periodically from the doInBackground method  I am alrady using Handler but it does not work?

Comment: Same as End Game. Handler is good in this case. Why don't it work?

Comment: "I am alrady using Handler". Try to see my answer and use the handler in onPostExecute() and not in doInBackground()

Comment: I'd open a socket and allow the server to push the data when it changes rather than a http request every x seconds

Comment: did you try using Adapters and notifyDatasetChanged pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code in you onPostExecute()

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MyAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    }, 5*60*1000); // this is for a gap of 5 minutes
```

Comment: I added some code to see what I have alrady done. I thought onPostExecute is being called when the doInBackground method is finshed?!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understand what you want, update information from server continuous. Still using `Handler`, but by this way:

```
final Handler updateInfoHandler;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    updateInfoHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //code update infomation
            updateInfoHandler.postDelayed(this, 60000);//auto update info each 60s
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @Noguyen: Please see my code I have did it like you?!

Comment: In my case, I make the Handler loop every 60s. With your code, handler only run a time, after 5mins. Is it right?

Comment: my handler runs once every 2 minutes